# Is there a security risk to having node.js installed on a shared server?

Tags: node.js

I have installed "node.js" on a shared server. I have rename the directory so that it can not be found easily.  Also I have my node directory in a location above /public_html.

I have also installed node on my PC for programming and testing easy on my local system vrs my web server.

What I would like to know is does this create a security risk where someone could hack my sites if they knew where my node installation files exist?

I have not added the path to my bash, so the commands have to be executed manually by using the ~ representing home, and the path. Such as:

```
~/pathtodir/bin/npm -v
```